# Getting the last segment of an URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, userscripts

Let's say that this is my URL/Link that i have written in an input

https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH/

How can I get the "CBt-W4jHZjH" part?

var link = ?????

```
var a = link.val().trim();
var regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/);
var validation = regex.test(a);
```

Comment: `'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH/'.match(/\/([^/]+)\/$/)[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```js
const getLastPath = (url) => {
  url = new URL(url);
  const pathname = url.pathname; 
  const paths = pathname.split("/"); 
  return paths.pop() || paths.pop();
}


console.log(getLastPath("https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH/")); // "CBt-W4jHZjH"
console.log(getLastPath("https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH"));  // "CBt-W4jHZjH"
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it. One way is to look for [/ any character but / ending with / end of line.](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5C%2F%28%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%29%5C%2F%3F%24%2F)

```js
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH/'
var x = new URL(url);
console.log(x.pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1])
```

Could be done with split. The filter removes the empty string caused by the trailing `/`.

```js
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBt-W4jHZjH/'
var x = new URL(url);
console.log(x.pathname.split('/').filter(x=>x).pop());
```

Comment: Does it really worth it using URL API for the sake of a single `pathname` property? Why not applying `match()` to URL string directly? And it is supposed to work without forward slash escaped within square brackets.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yeah, it could be done to the string. But I like the URL way.

Comment: I've been thinking of a different way to make it fancy (`const [,hash] = .match(/\/([^/]+)\/$/)`), but then got lazy and posted my ugly comment under OP ;)